# Having trouble updating a <p> tag with JavaScript IF a condition is met

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the html below:

```
<div class="t_gray t_small mb_10">
<p class="t_bold pt_5 oos_msg">CAD $0.00</p>
<p class="pt_5 oos">Batman Graphic Tee - Out Of Stock</p>
</div>

<div class="t_gray t_small mb_10">
<p class="t_bold pt_5 oos_msg">CAD $14.99</p>
<p class="pt_5 oos">Superman Flying Graphic Tee</p>
</div>

<div class="t_gray t_small mb_10">
<p class="t_bold pt_5 oos_msg">CAD $0.00</p>
<p class="pt_5 oos">Spiderman vs Venom Hoodie - Out Of Stock</p>
</div>

<div class="t_gray t_small mb_10">
<p class="t_bold pt_5 oos_msg">CAD $9.99</p>
<p class="pt_5 oos">Wolverine vs Magento Tank</p>
</div>

<div class="t_gray t_small mb_10">
<p class="t_bold pt_5 oos_msg">CAD $0.00</p>
<p class="pt_5 oos">Hulk vs Thanos - Out Of Stock</p>
</div>
```

I'm using the function below to update the text in the 'P' tag with class 'oos_msg' IF a condition is met.

```
$('.oos').text(function() {
  if ($('.oos:contains("Out Of Stock")')) {
    $('.oos_msg').html('Out Of Stock');
  }
})
```

The problem I'm having is that it's updating every single 'P' tag, which has a class oos_msg, what am I doing wrong?

JSFiddle link:
https://jsfiddle.net/jingz/3r5L84e6/17/

Comment: _every single 'P' tag,_... I would say "every single 'P' tag, which has a class `oos_msg`" as expected. Isn't it?

Comment: I probably didn't explain my self correctly, i suck at explaining - What I want to do is if the p tag has the words "Out Of Stock" to update the p tag with class "oos_msg". What my code is doing is updating all p tags whether the words "Out Of Stock" are in it or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems:

- Your `$('.oos_msg')` selector selects **all** of the `.oos_msg` elements, so all of them will have their `.html()` updated.
- Your `$('.oos:contains()')` also has the same problem -- if **any** of them contain that text, then the conditional will be triggered.

To correct this, you can use **[`$(this)`](http://html-tuts.com/jquery-this-selector/)** to only target the current element that you're looping over, in conjunction with **[`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/)** and the **[`:contains` selector](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)** to handle the contained text.

This can be seen in the following:

```js
$('.oos').text(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':contains("Out Of Stock")'))
    $(this).prev().html('Out Of Stock');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="t_gray t_small mb_10">
  <p class="t_bold pt_5 oos_msg">CAD $0.00</p>
  <p class="pt_5 oos">Batman Graphic Tee - Out Of Stock</p>
</div>

<div class="t_gray t_small mb_10">
  <p class="t_bold pt_5 oos_msg">CAD $0.00</p>
  <p class="pt_5 oos">Superman Flying Graphic Tee</p>
</div>

<div class="t_gray t_small mb_10">
  <p class="t_bold pt_5 oos_msg">CAD $0.00</p>
  <p class="pt_5 oos">Spiderman vs Venom Hoodie - Out Of Stock</p>
</div>

<div class="t_gray t_small mb_10">
  <p class="t_bold pt_5 oos_msg">CAD $0.00</p>
  <p class="pt_5 oos">Wolverine vs Magento Tank</p>
</div>

<div class="t_gray t_small mb_10">
  <p class="t_bold pt_5 oos_msg">CAD $0.00</p>
  <p class="pt_5 oos">Hulk vs Thanos - Out Of Stock</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome this works, thanks a lot! I need to read more on $(this) and .is(). :)